# issubclass of abstract base class Sequence

Tags: python, subclassing, duck-typing, isinstance, abstract-base-class

[This list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) shows what methods you need to implement for your class to be "regarded" as Sequence: `__getitem__`, `__len__`, `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__reversed__`, `index`, and `count`. So why does this minimal implementation does not work, i.e. why `issubclass(S, Sequence) is False`?

```
from collections import *


class S(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        raise IndexError

    def __len__(self):
        return 0

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return False

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(())

    def __reversed__(self):
        return self

    def index(self, item):
        raise IndexError

    def count(self, item):
        return 0


issubclass(S, Iterable)   # True  :-)
issubclass(S, Sized)      # True  :-)
issubclass(S, Container)  # True  :-)
issubclass(S, Sequence)   # False :-(
```

Is there an additional method I need to implement that I overlooked? Did I misunderstand abstract base classes? Subclassing `Sequence` makes `issubclass` return `True` of course, but that kinda defeats the idea behind abc, doesn't it?

Comment: Just because a class implements the sequence interface does not make it a subclass of Sequence.

Comment: I think OP already knows that. See [abc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#module-abc).

Comment: To me there seems to be a disconnect here between what's colloquially considered a sequence in Python (`__len__` and `__getitem__` with ints) and what's formally considered a Sequence by the language (per `insinstance`). As it stands, you cannot look at an object's methods and decide whether it is formally considered a sequence, which is weird to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[*Use the source, Luke!*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/_abcoll.py)

`Sequence` does not implement its own `__subclasshook__`, and all the implementations of `__subclasshook__` from the parents of `Sequence` have checks like this:

```
class Iterable:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        if cls is Iterable:  # <<<<
            if _hasattr(C, "__iter__"):
                return True
        return NotImplemented
```

You can however explicitly [`register()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register) your class as a `Sequence`:

```
Sequence.register(S)
```

As for the reason why `Sequence` does not implement `__subclasshook__`, see [issue 16728](http://bugs.python.org/issue16728) (which title was initially *"collections.abc.Sequence shoud provide __subclasshook__"*). The issue can be summarized by saying that a sequence can be many things, depending on the needs of who uses it:

> Many algorithms that require a sequence only need `__len__` and `__getitem__`. [...] `collections.abc.Sequence` is a much richer interface.

Comment: In other words collections.Sequence is pointless (/incomplete) unless used as a mixin?

Comment: @Kay: it give you the features of many other abstract base classes: you get an exception if you try to inherit without defining all the required methods, and you can explicit `register()` arbitrary subclasses

Comment: Hm, seems like an blatant oversight by the Python hackers to my to be honest. Do you know a reason why `Sequence.__subclasshook__` is not implemented?

Comment: @Kay: `__subclasshook__` is a bit pointless. Example: having an attribute `__iter__` does not imply that an instance has correctly implemented an iterable.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand the problem.